# No error squigglys in IntelliJ community when working with Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

[image]I downloaded and installed IntelliJ telling community edition on my Mac running High Sierra.

I opened a Java project in it and did a mvn install in command-line.

The IDE asked me to reference a JDK so I did that.

When editing code in the project I am getting no error squigglys for bad code. For example I can delete a variable that is being used all over the file and the IDE doesn't tell me there is a problem. I can write jibberish in the file and the IDE doesn't tell me there is a problem. Obviously it won't build, but I want these warnings before I build.

Coming from Visual Studio the experience has been horrible so far.

Comment: @imustbesomeone yes when I first loaded the project it said that, but I believe I resolved it correctly by pointing to JDK 8 on my machine. The message went away. Anything you recommend I check?

Comment: @ImustbeSomeone I uploaded a screenshot of the Project structure screen. When you say workspace what do you want me to take a ss of?

Comment: @BlakeRivell Did you import the project from Maven? Do you see the blue source roots in the project view? Also make sure Power Save mode is not enabled in File menu. Provide the screenshot of the entire IDE window including the editor and the project view showing the location of the class file in a tree if the issue persists.

Comment: @CrazyCoder this is a maven project with a pom. I did a mvn install.

Comment: @BlakeRivell You've managed to skip the most important questions in my comment somehow, actually not a single one is answered :)

Comment: @CrazyCoder sorry, yes I see blue source roots in the project view. Powersaving mode is disabled.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I figured it out. Instead of opening the folder I did an import project and selected the .pom file. Now everything is recognized!